# Can't load main class JUnitStarter when running tests on remote host via SSH on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ssh, junit, java-8

I'm wanting to run tests on another more powerful machine to speed up testing time, so I've created a run configuration on Intellij which targets my Ubuntu machine rather than my local one.

If I don't use rsync to copy the files to the remote target, the tests all work fine, however when I enable rsync in IntelliJ, I get the following exception when the tests attempt to start:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Although I could run without rsync enabled, the copy process to the remote host takes longer than running the tests on my local machine.

For context, my local machine is running Windows 10, and my remote machine is running Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

After doing a bit more digging, I found that rsync is copying files in the maven repository and Intellij Ultimate folder using the MS-DOS file structure style. This means that as part of the copy, it's using backslashes instead of forward slashes resulting in linux thinking it's part of the name of the .jar file. In result, it means that the copied maven repository folder is in the wrong file structure:
[image: Screenshot of copied maven repository from windows to linux using rsync in IntelliJ]

Changing the file structure manually fixed the issue and tests run successfully however it's just a work around and doesn't directly fix the problem but at least points in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270106
Will be helpful if you can vote for it and attach idea logs there

Comment: I've done some more digging into the issue, and left a comment on the jetbrains issue as well. Unfortunately I can't post logs in there due to work related reasons but I have updated my answer with some information pointing in the correct direction. Thanks for the link!